# How to add button to custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-imagebutton

I am using [FunDapter](https://github.com/amigold/FunDapter) for my project.When i try to add imagebutton to my layout other texts become unclickable.Does nothing when i click them.How can i add button to this adapter?

Below is list_layout where everything works fine

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Isimsiz"
    android:id="@+id/Housename"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textColor="#241d1d"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />



    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Aciklama Yok"
    android:id="@+id/Desc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Housename"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Housename"
    android:textColor="#241d1d"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Housename" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

When i add image button nothing is clickable except imagebutton

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Housename"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Desc"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="berk"
    />
```

And this is part of the class where i create my adapter

```
   public void processFinish(String s) {
    productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);
    BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
    dict.addStringField(R.id.Housename, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return product.HouseID;
        }
    });

    dict.addStringField(R.id.Desc, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return product.Desc;
        }
    });


    FunDapter<Product> adapter = new FunDapter<>(
    ListActivity.this, productList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);

    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //do sth
}
public void berk(View v) {
    //do sth
}
```

Note:Also when i give clickable attribute to texts in xml they stop working.Like When i play with layout XML everything stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First of all if u are using button or edit text in your adapter or row file Then every thing will get stop working .
You should use

1.Set descendant Focusablity="before Descendants" in the list view.
2.Set window Soft Input Mode="adjust Pan" in the manifest
3.Set list view.set Items Can Focus(true)
```

Comment: I made softinoutmode and added these two lines  lvProduct.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        lvProduct.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);  Still only button works listrows does not

Answer (score 1):

In Adapter Class

`public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicals_details_row, parent, false);
    Button deleteImageView = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.DeleteImageView);
    deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //...
        }
    });
}`

But you can get an issue - listView row not clickable. Solution:

- make ListView focusable android:focusable="true"
- Button not focusable  android:focusable="false"

Comment: I dont understand what that code does.I dont have simiar code.Btw i did make that 2 focusable solutions but did not work

Answer (score 0):

you have to give separate click event for all views.

> Your ImageButton has android:clickable="true" which makes sub view clickable. But you other views are not clickable.

Solution

For click event in textview

> textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>           public void onClick(View v) {
>               //...
>           }
>       });
>   similar for Imagebutton 
>   
>  remove
>
> android:clickable="true"

hope it helps.